# How can i use PHP hide some charracter in a text

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to hide some characters in a text with a symbol.

For example:
I want to convert 0024009302 to ******9302, thereby hiding about six characters in the text.

Please someone should help cos am new to this

Thank you.

Comment: How is that related to mysql or sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your requirement is not that clear but you could start from here:

```
$text = "0024009302";
echo str_pad(substr($text, 6), strlen($text), "*", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: What if the length of the input number is more or less?

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to achieve this,

```php
<?php


function EncodePhoneNumber($Number='', $first=0, $last=0, $rep='*'){
    $begin  = substr($Number,0,$first);
    $middle = str_repeat($rep,strlen(substr($Number,$first,$last)));
    $end    = substr($Number, $last);
    $stars  = $begin.$middle.$end;
    return $stars;
}
$string = '12345678910';
echo EncodePhoneNumber($string,0,-3);

?>
```